# Undefined symbols error when using mingw to generate dynamic library under windows，but linux does not

Tags: windows, gcc, dll, linker, mingw

I have a file called helloworld.c, which depends on an external dynamic library called libhello.dll.

```
/* helloworld.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(void);

int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to compile helloworld.c into a dynamic library. I install mingw under windows, then I use the command：

`gcc -shared -fPIC -o libhelloworld.dll hello_world.c`

Something terrible happened, the command reported an error:

```
undefined reference to `hello'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I must explicitly specify the dependent library to compile：

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libhelloworld.dll hello_world.c -L. -lhello
```

This is very stupid, this doesn't happen in linux, undefined symbols are allowed when generating dynamic libraries under linux, why not under windows.

Is there any way to make windows behave like linux, without using -L and -l to specify the path and name of the dynamic library when generating the dynamic library? Such as adding some compile options and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error makes sense: you have a forward declaration for `void hello(void);` but no actual implementation of that function.

So the compiler will work (e.g. with `gcc -c -o hello_world.o hello_world.c`), but the linker doesn't know where to find the `hello()` function (e.g. with `gcc -o libhelloworld.exe hello_world.o`).

The solution is define the actual body for `hello()`, either in `helloworld.c`, or in a seperate `.c` file that is compiled and linked into the same output file, or via a library (`.a` file linked via `-l` flag).

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I mean when generating dynamic library in linux, undefined symbols are allowed, so `gcc -shared -fPIC -o libhelloworld.so hello_world.c`  command will not error under linux. But under windows it gives error.

Comment: I want to generate a dynamic library, although it depends on many other dynamic libraries, but I don't want to specify which libraries it depends on when generating the dynamic library. This works under linux, but in windows it gives an error.

Comment: On Windows undefined symbols are not allowed. In other words: you can't make `.exe` or `.dll` files that have symbols that are unresolved (= not pointing to actual code). This is by design on Windows and is independent of which compiler/linker you use.